# ASP.NET MVC Error: 'System.Web.Helpers.Validation' does not contain a definition for 'RequireField'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I have created empty project and have been following this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/working-with-pages/4-working-with-forms):

But i am getting the following error:

[image]

Here is my **WebConfig** in Views folder:

[image]

What can be causing the problem?

Still getting the error:
[image]

Comment: typo. should be RequireFields. Which version of MVC are you using? 3 or 4?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is a typo. it should be Validation.RequiredFields

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.validationhelper.requirefields(v=vs.111).aspx

**Update**: Most likely you need to upgrade to Web Matrix 2 (ASP.NET WebPages 2.0)

Comment: sadly, still getting the error, added screen to question

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Which version of MVC are you using? 3 or 4?

Comment: .Net version 4.5 , MVC 5

Comment: Try upgrading to ASP.NET WebPages 2.0 (Web Matrix 2)

Comment: did you upgrade to WebPages 2.0?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48970/discussion-between-ahmed-ilyas-and-dyk)

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the contents of the bin folder from a project that worked before and that worked very well